# Testing a Rails controller action with RSpec’s post method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a very simple controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Thing.do_stuff
  end
end
```

…And a very simple spec:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe ThingsController do
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "does stuff with things" do
      expect(Thing).to receive(:do_stuff)
      controller.create # This works
      post :create # This does not work
    end
  end
end
```

I am not running the direct invocation and the `post` request at the same time. Invoking the action on the controller directly passes the assertion, but invoking the action through the `post` method does not. It appears `do_stuff` is never called on `Thing`. Why might that be?

Comment: Do you get anything useful from `response.body`?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered what my issue was.

Invoking the controller directly keeps the spec isolated and ignores things like a `before_action` in the `ApplicationController`.

When we start using the `post` method, it’s really an integrated test and hits things like authentication. I couldn’t hit my controller method because my test user wasn’t signed in.